# c# reference assembly in relative path the simple way

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly

I set up a directory that goes "app/data". When I compile, the exe is copied to app, and my assemblies "asm1" and "asm2" are copied to data. Since the assemblies need to be located in the same path as the exe, it won't run. Is there a way to reference the assemblies in that relative path? Other methods I've found not to be very effective like using `obj = Assembly.LoadFrom` with requires having to do `obj.method` every time. Does anyone have a simple way to do this so that it is just like usual except in a different path? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: why do you consider those assemblies to be "data"?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You're actually making this more complicated, for a reason you haven't explained.  Atm, the correct answer is *don't do this*.

Comment: I do know that I could just keep them in the same dir, but for organization purposes, I like to keep my assemblies in a relative path. Believe me there is too much stuff in the app part of the dir that it would be a nightmare.

Comment: I do suppose that the above question does fit to what I need to an extent thus I will consider it the answer. I do thank you guys for the help and sorry for the duplicate as I couldn't find that anywhere.